# Is there a word or expression to call someone who easily gives credit, especially to insignificant efforts?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

A common example would be a professor who is too mild in his marking of a poor assignments. 
Another example could be someone who doesn't add or say much with his words, but still receives a lot of credit (*gets a lot of votes) from voters during an election. 
Another example might be a rather poor musical performance which, however, is being (too) highly praised by the audience. A mum, who praises her 10 year old son too easily on tasks (such as, getting dressed, drinking his cup with two hands, ignoring his teat) that a 4 year old would normally be praised on.

Comment: It seems that you're asking two different questions, or a word which encompasses two different concepts: one who gives too much credit and one who gets too much credit.

Comment: In the examples, I meant: the professor who gives too much credit, too easily to his students; the voters giving credit too easily; and the audience in the concerthall praising the performance too highly (, too easily).

Comment: This is one of those questions (or two actually) where context and motivation of the subject play a role in the word choice.  If the instructor who grades too leniently does so because of timidity and fear of confrontation, that's one thing...if it's done because of showing favoritism, that's something else again.  Can you add context to your question(s)?

Comment: The thing is, that I don't know, unfortunately, why it is done. I only saw it happening and wonder what it is called.

Comment: If the instructor grades leniently across the board, then you can rule out favoritism, right?  So you probably do know more than you realize. :-)

Comment: @user76935: It's done for many different reasons. Two as set out in my answer. And if the *electorate* award votes to what you think of as "undeserving" candidates, maybe you're just not in touch with the mood of the people, who think he *is* the best candidate. Or maybe they're casting protest votes ("a plague on all your houses"), maybe they're just voting along tribal/class lines, maybe it's "tactical voting", etc., etc.

Comment: The question is too broad. There may be too many reasons that account for the behaviours described in the question.!!

Answer (score 1):

The professor sounds like someone who is *lax* in their grading. He allows for a lot of mistakes in the work of his students. You could say the voters were *lenient* on their judgement of the politician. Or maybe that they are *easy to please*. The same goes for the crowd. *Easygoing, (over)permissive, or over-tolerant* are similar words you could use in similar situations.

Comment: Without context or known motivation, this is one of several possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The only word I can think of for someone/an entity (a crowd, etc.) who gives affirmation too easily is a *pushover*.

> Clear, concise, fair, but no pushover! An outstanding prof!
>
> I just got the attached paper back with "A+ Incredibly Well Done, I'm Impressed" on it. What a pushover that prof is!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say OP's professor could be called...

> [**indulgent**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indulgent) *- having or indicating a readiness or over-readiness to be generous to or lenient with someone*

Of course, there might be justifiable/cynical reasons for such behaviour. Perhaps the prof thinks that by (excessively) praising even *small* efforts made by his students, he might get them interested in masking *greater* efforts to gain even more praise. Most parents do this a lot, because they want to teach their children to value praise.

Another possibility is [an indulgent audience](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an%20indulgent%20crowd%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22an%20indulgent%20audience%22&tbm=bks) at, say, the World Championship Snooker Final. If one of the finalists is having an "off day", the crowd may well erupt in resounding applause when he finally pots a ball. They came to watch a hard-fought match, not a walkover, so they naturally want to encourage the faltering player to take heart and even things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As a general term, those you tend to give credit easily can be considered **superficial** in the sense of:

> - displaying a lack of thoroughness or care:
> - concerned with or comprehending only what is apparent or obvious;